# CSS change element width from different direction

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a div that contains an image element set up as such:

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="cat.jpg"/>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}

#container img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: none;
}
```

Currently the container width is smaller then the img width meaning that right part of the image is cropped out which is what I want. However, I would like the left part of the image to be cut out instead.

I've tried experimenting with background positioning but haven't gotten what I wanted. Does anyone know of the correct way to achieve this?

To clarify, I would like to achieve the effect represented in the blue box below (where the faded out section isn't actually visible of course):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple solution...

**HTML**

```
<div class="cat"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cat {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('http://www.deargrumpycat.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Grumpy-Cat1.jpg');
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: 200px 200px; // set bg size
    height: 200px; // no need for container
    width: 150px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/emDNp/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by floating the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/9AmVA/2/

```
#container {
  /* Making crop dimensions bigger so I can see the edge of the cat to know it's working correctly */
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container:after { clear: right;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: ' '; }

#container img {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 200px
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("PATH-TO/YOUR-IMAGE.JPG");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

By using background size and position you will have much more control over the positioning or composing the image. you can automate this using javascript as well.
I would suggest not to use id's instead use className or data attribute.